# Transparent PNG - BufferedImage contains not existing pixels - java

Tags: java, png, transparency, bufferedimage

I have got BufferedImage and method getRGB(...) shows me pixel in position 456, 1959, but I cannot see any color in this position in any image editor.
I have got two images with transparency. ImageOne was created in my java application. ImageTwo is ImageOne (ImageOne was open in Affinity Photo and saved as ImageTwo without any change).

If I open ImageOne or ImageTwo in any image editor I can see two same images.
Images to download: [ImageOne + ImageTwo](https://filebin.net/7krbrduo6iyp24jz/ImageOneTwo.ZIP?t=6bcfpc3l) or [HERE](https://ulozto.net/file/TuasC5TJWT1S/imageonetwo-zip) or [HERE](https://www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/KMM5N2TVE7ZIAJ8K-3CX/SWTYUPG6WE)

But in java application it seems, that images are different. This code print RGB color for pixel 456, 1959

```
    private static void testImage() {
    try {
        File fOne = new File("d:\\test\\ImageOne.png");
        File fTwo = new File("d:\\test\\ImageTwo.png");
        
        BufferedImage imageOne = ImageIO.read(fOne);
        BufferedImage imageTwo = ImageIO.read(fTwo);
        
        Color cOne = new Color(imageOne.getRGB(456, 1959));
        System.out.println("imageOne = " + cOne.getRGB() + " RGBA = " + cOne.getRed() + "," + cOne.getGreen() + "," + cOne.getBlue() + "," + cOne.getAlpha());
        
        Color cTwo = new Color(imageTwo.getRGB(456, 1959));
        System.out.println("imageTwo = " + cTwo.getRGB() + " RGBA = " + cTwo.getRed() + "," + cTwo.getGreen() + "," + cTwo.getBlue() + "," + cTwo.getAlpha());
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
imageOne = -8355712 RGBA = 128,128,128,255
imageTwo = -16777216 RGBA = 0,0,0,255
```

Is it possible to clear BufferedImage from these "invisible" pixels?
Have you any idea why is pixel in ImageOne and why I can see it only in java? Why is the pixel "invisible" for image editors?
Thank you.

Comment: Your code has a (very understandable) flaw, in that you use the `Color` constructor with a single int parameter. This constructor *discards* the alpha component ("Creates an opaque sRGB color... Alpha is defaulted to 255"). A very confusing API, indeed. So you are *not* printing the actual alpha values for the pixel. Change to `new Color(imageOne.getRGB(456, 1959), true)` to get the correct value. Most likely, the pixels *are transparent*, even though the explanation given in @Hiran's answer is incorrect. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this is totally legit. The alpha channel is 255, which means the ink is fully transparent.

This assumption is wrong as per https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Alpha-channel:
*An alpha value of zero represents full transparency, and a value of (2^bitdepth)-1 represents a fully opaque pixel.*

Which means I do not have an explanation why in graphics programs the picture should be looking the same - which is the symptom originally described.

Comment: *"Your alpha channel is 255, which means the ink is fully transparent."* Actually, it's the other way around. 255 or 0xFF means fully *opaque*. 0 is transparent.